# delayMicroseconds- error?

Tags: arduino-mega

running a very short program on a mega, just to generate a 8 microsecond wide clock pulse on pin 18, every 250 microseconds-
closest 'delay' values I can get are delayMicroseconds(3), and (83) off, gives a 7.5 microsecond wide pulse every 249 microseconds- any suggestions on a better way?

here is whats running:

```
int i=0;
int req=18;

void setup(){
Serial.begin(115200);
 DDRD = DDRD | B10000010;
 interrupts();
pinMode(req,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
i=1;
digitalWrite(req, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(3); //gives 7.5 microsecond pulse?
digitalWrite(req, LOW);

while(i<83){//gives 249 microseconds start of pulse to start of next pulse?
 delayMicroseconds(1);
 i=(i+1);}
 }
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use PWM?

Comment: from what I understand, PWM frequency is 'roughly' 490 hz, I need exactly 4000 hz. is there a listing of instruction processing times published somewhere for calculating overhead? Micros will give the whole thing, but not just the while-loop

Comment: Only if you stick to what Arduino gives you. Breaking outside the box makes things more flexible all around.

Comment: Try out the TimerOne library.

Comment: thanks guys- rethinking, reading Micros at various parts of the program can let me shift timing as needed to read next bit in the next byte- will only work for static conditions, but thats OK for now. Thanks for suggesting PWM- yes standard it clocks very slow, but it is accurate- the pulse duration of 1% just happened to give a 8 microsecond tick, triggering the device to send- the extremely long off time it didnt mind at all. thanks for the comments- this things all pretty new to me, but i see a ton of potential for building tools to repair our CNC components :)

Answer (score 2):

This a very partial answer. I do not know your requirements, whether or
not PWM can do the job, etc... I just wanted to point out that you can
make a pulse exactly 8 µs long with this:

```c
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/atomic.h>

// Pulse PD3 (digital 18 on Mega 2560)
// for exactly 8 us (128 clock cycles @ 16 MHz)
static void pulse() {
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        PORTD |= 1 << 3;
        _delay_us(8 - 0.125);
        PORTD &= ~(1 << 3);
    }
}
```

The `_delay_us()` function from avr-libc is actually cycle-accurate
inline assembly. The 0.125 µs I subtracted is the time needed by
the actual port writes: both the sbi and cbi instructions take two cycles
(0.125 µs), but that delay should only be counted once.
`digitalWrite()` should always be avoided in time-critical code.

The 242 µs delay between pulses would be harder to generate without
PWM. A timer interrupt at 4 kHz seems like the simplest option, but
it is not cycle-accurate.

**Edit**: here is the scope trace, showing a quite accurate timing:

[image: oscilloscope trace]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want program PWM timer as suggested in comment then for short delays you need calculate how many instruction cycles are needed to make such a delay based on clock/crystal frequency and make that delay in inline assembler to have code under control. To manipulate digital output use writing data to PINx (which is equal to xoring PORTx).

To satisfy exact 250ms you need compensate errors because of rounding. Arduino's delay/tick functions do it. For the long delays you need a simple scheduler not to spend all the CPU time for pulse generating.